# Peano system vs natural numbers

Tags: logic, natural-numbers, peano-axioms

What exactly is the difference between natural numbers and an arbitrary peano system? In particular there is a proof in my book for recursion on natural numbers, as well as an erroneous proof of recursion for peano system. I have tried looking at the definitions but the difference escapes me. Really appreciate your help

Comment: Arbitrary peano systems may contain additional objects; not just those belonging to $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Does that change at all the behavior of the system, or are all peano systems isomorphic to natural numbers?

Comment: The model of Peano system contains 'standard' natural numbers, but every model of (first-order) Peano system is not isomorphic to the standard model of PA. There is a model of PA that contains the 'nonstandard' natural numbers.

Comment: @Liza The latter, with the qualification that 'all peano systems' is changed to 'the standard peano system'.

Comment: Does the transfinite recursion then hold for a standrand peano system since it is well ordered? I was having an argument with someone and I was told it doesnt which really puzzled me. Nonstandard natural numbers seem like a fastinating concept though, thank you for pointing me in that direction

Comment: @Liza Your interlocutor was wrong, transfinite recursion does hold for the standard peano system, because it's well-founded (this follows from the induction axiom).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that

Comment: @Human Rostomyan: The induction axiom in PA does *not* imply that the ordering is well-founded. The order type of the non-standard models is discussed in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model_of_arithmetic. Non-standard models are never well-founded.

Comment: @RobArthan But the comment you are responding to does not say this, does it? It just says that the standard Peano system, _i.e._ $(\mathbb{N};0,S,+,\times,<)$ is well-founded, which is true. (Although the induction principle that implies this is not the first-order induction scheme of $\mathsf{PA}$, as you point out, but rather the definition of $\mathbb{N}$ in set theory as the least inductive set.)

Comment: I don't see that there is any useful distinction to be made between the natural numbers and an arbitrary Peano system, which I assume to be mean any set $X$ on which the Peano axioms hold for a suitable successor function $S: X\rightarrow X$.